# iPhone it seems like when i call the setFullscreen method of MPMoviePlayerController  does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like my video t0 start full screen, I'm calling the following method
[ mp setFullscreen: yes];
It seems like it is nt doing anything, if I comment it out the video player runs the same.  When the player does run, there is a icon on the right hand side with 2 arrows, seems like pressing it puts it in full screen.

Am I doing something g wrong??

(void)viewDidLoad {

```
    // save it in a fix file name for testing documets\ted.mp4
NSURL *url  = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
               URLForResource:@"FredCouplesDriv"
               withExtension:@"mov"];

mp=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
[mp.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview: mp.view];

// Set movie player layout
[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];

// set full screen
[mp setFullscreen:YES];


// May help to reduce latency
[mp prepareToPlay];

[mp play];
  [mp setFullscreen:YES];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];

  [self.view bringSubviewToFront: mStop ];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `[mp setFullscreen:YES];` to `viewDidAppear` and you'll be fine

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [mp setFullscreen:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank YOU!!!!!!! I was going around in circles reading gapless doc and tutorials.